# Introduction to aircraft performance

Tags: aerospace

How do determine the power available and the power required for an aeroplane in a steady level flight=

Comment: This is much too broad.

Comment: Can you at least give one solution?

Comment: Sure.  Trim the airplane in level flight-  that’s the power required.  Then push the throttle all the way forward. That’s the power available.

Comment: Re "Introduction to aircraft performance" -- is that the actual name of the class, for which you are asking a homework question?

Comment: yes sir, is that an issue?

Comment: yes, it is an issue because you don't say what you have tried to understand, and what is not clear to you after you have studied.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am new on this site. I am a first-year Aerospace Engineering student. I haven't taken any courses related to this field but this. I will delete my question.

Comment: you should not delete your question, you should [edit](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/93663/edit) it and add the relevant information: what you searched on your own, what you found, and why you're not satisfied with what you found. Also, now you jumped to accept the answer, so you can't delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power required for steady level flight is glide ratio × weight at a given airspeed.

> Power = Force × Velocity = mass × m/sec$^2$ × m/sec = mass × V$^2$/sec

So you work to draw your drag curve at various airspeeds.

> Thrust = Drag in level steady state flight.

Then you determine what type of performance envelope you want.  Just like cars, economical or sporty.  Conveniently, **fuel burn** can also be expressed as Energy/sec or mass × V$^2$/sec and, over a given distance: mass × V$^3$

Generally, you want at least enough **excess thrust** available to maintain a safe climb rate (in case of downdraft) for a given **weight**.

Comment: None of this actually answers the question (as unspecific as it may be), and along with factual errors (e.g. glide ratio times weight is not power) and the bolding of unrelated terms it reads more as a post geared to SEO.

Comment: @Raketenolli this is about as unconstructive a comment as I have ever seen here.  See the equation right underneath the statement "Power required for steady state level flight ... **at a given airspeed**" Anything wrong there?  Important points were **bolded** for the benefit of the person asking the question (not you).  Before you cite "factual errors", try reading a bit further.  BTW what is **your** definition of performance?

Comment: Yes, I did read them. But the question is not "introduction to aircraft performance", but "How do I determine the power required (and available) for an aeroplane in steady level flight?". You state that power is force times velocity. Which is true. But then you start multiplying physical quantities (mass) with units (m, sec) for no apparent reason and no additional value. You only vaguely hint at where the force and the velocity that you want to multiply come from. You say the OP should determine what type of performance envelope he wants. Which again, is unrelated to answering the question...

Comment: ... fuel burn was similarly never asked for and you mention that you "want at least enough excess thrust" which might be remotely related to the part of "power available" in the question, but doesn't actually answer it.
I downvoted, so I felt like I needed to explain why I did so, which was, admittedly, a very sweeping and not very detailed judgement, but if I had wanted to be very constructive, I would have simply answered the question the way I would have wanted it to be answered, but it was already closed.

Comment: @Raketenolli thanks for responding.  It just so happens that thrust requirement for level flight (in pounds) can be rather accurately determined by multiplying glide ratio by **the weight of the aircraft**.  This is a well known technique.  F = Ma.  It works, and is in fact in the question as "power required" and **can be directly linked to fuel burn**.  Fuel burn is linked to *engine size and weight*.  This is a starting point for design.

Comment: "Vauge hint"  draw drag curve at various airspeeds.  Glide ratios will differ on both sides of Vbg, but, lucky for us, good ol' gravity is constant.  Maybe a good cup of coffee will help us.